# SPICE simulation of MOSFET switch

Tags: mosfet, spice

Trying to understand the SPICE output for this basic MOSFET circuit:

[image]

The input (left) is a crude square wave:

[image]

A simple spice simulation shows the output voltage (right) as follows:

[image]

Why does the capacitor level off at 7V?  My thinking was that as it charges up, the current through the transistor would decrease until V<sub>DS</sub> = 0, and at that point the voltage across the capacitor would be 9V, but SPICE thinks differently.

Comment: nmos cuts off when \$V_{GS} \lt V_{th}\$, so the maximum voltage the capacitor charges to is \$V_{DD}-V_{th}\$.  replace it with pmos to  get full output

Comment: ohhhh, right.  can you please make this an answer?  i will accept it now.

Comment: @broken.eggshell Put another way, you accidentally built an NMOS [source follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain) instead of a PMOS high-side switch, which is what it looks like you wanted.

Comment: Yeah I saw that immediately following the first comment, but it took someone to point it out to me.  Still trying to internalize this stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nmos cuts off when \$V_{GS} \lt V_{th}\$, so the maximum voltage an nmos can "pass" is \$V_{DD}-V_{th}\$.

pmos cuts off when \$V_{GS} \gt -V_{th}\$, so the minimum voltage an pmos can "pass" is \$V_{SS}+V_{th}\$.